# file descriptor not generated

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh

I am facing a problem in a shell script. I narrowed down the problem and found that it is because of a file descriptor from standard input which is not generated in proc file system.
Here below is the test script that i have written:

```
#!/bin/ksh


var=`ls -lrt /proc/$$/path/0`
echo $var


if [[  -f /proc/$$/path/0 ]]
then
echo "found file descriptor"
else
echo "file descriptor not found"
fi
```

I tested this in /tmp/ directory with a sample input file:

```
$ ./checkip.sh < /tmp/testip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 31 09:15 /proc/19358/path/0 -> /tmp/testip
found file descriptor
```

Now I tested in one of the directory where we are facing a problem.

```
$ ./checkip.sh < /var/opt/xxxxxxxx/testip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 31 09:15 /proc/20124/path/0
file descriptor not found
$
```

I thought may be it is with the directory xxxxxxxx. so I tested this again with a file in the parent directory.

```
$ ./checkip.sh < /var/opt/testip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 31 09:16 /proc/21286/path/0 -> /var/opt/testip
found file descriptor
$
```

It worked again. But i donot see any difference between directory permissions of opt and xxxxxxxx

```
$ ls -l |grep xxxxxxxx
drwxr-xr-x 292 abcdefg   abc         8192 Dec 31 08:33 xxxxxxxx
$ cd ..
$ ls -l | grep opt
drwxr-xr-x  17 abcdefg   abc          512 Dec 31 09:14 opt
```

I am confused about why the symbolic link for 0(standard input) is not created correctly.
Can anyone pls help me to find the reason for this?

**EDIT**-for the comment

file does not exist

```
$ ./checkip.sh < /tmp/notexistfile
/tmp/notexistfile: No such file or directory.
```

file  exists

```
$ ./checkip.sh < /var/opt/testip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 31 10:49 /proc/15917/path/0 -> /var/opt/testip
found file descriptor
```

file  exists

```
$ ./checkip.sh < /var/opt/xxxxxxxx/testip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 31 10:49 /proc/16566/path/0
file descriptor not found
$
```

The problem here I could see is the symbolic link for  standard input   in proc/pid/path/0 is not getting created for one directory. But what could be the reason..I am out of ideas!. Even the truss output does not show anything about how the file(sym link) proc/pid/path/0 is created.

Truss output: working case(check the stat64 call-succeeded):

```
9107/1:          0.0117 read(62, 0xFEF687A0, 1024)                      = 116
9107/1:            # ! / b i n / k s h\n\n i f   [ [     - f   / p r o c / $ $ / p
9107/1:            a t h / 0   ] ]\n t h e n\n e c h o   " f o u n d   f i l e   d
9107/1:            e s c r i p t o r "\n e l s e\n e c h o   " f i l e   d e s c r
9107/1:            i p t o r   n o t   f o u n d "\n f i\n
9107/1:          0.0118 sysconfig(6)                                    = 4096
9107/1:          0.0119 stat64(0x0808E630, 0x08089B40)                  = 0
9107/1:              0x0808E630: "/proc/9107/path/0"
9107/1:             d=0x04F40002 i=4191608033 m=0100644 l=1  u=308   g=205   sz=3
9107/1:                 at = Dec 31 08:33:06 GMT 2014  [ 1420014786.307569314 ]
9107/1:                 mt = Dec 31 08:33:06 GMT 2014  [ 1420014786.307619723 ]
9107/1:                 ct = Dec 31 08:33:06 GMT 2014  [ 1420014786.307619723 ]
9107/1:             bsz=4096  blks=8     fs=tmpfs
```

truss output: not working case(check the stat64 call-failure):

```
10125/1:         0.0057 read(62, 0xFEF687A0, 1024)                      = 116
10125/1:           # ! / b i n / k s h\n\n i f   [ [     - f   / p r o c / $ $ / p
10125/1:           a t h / 0   ] ]\n t h e n\n e c h o   " f o u n d   f i l e   d
10125/1:           e s c r i p t o r "\n e l s e\n e c h o   " f i l e   d e s c r
10125/1:           i p t o r   n o t   f o u n d "\n f i\n
10125/1:         0.0058 sysconfig(6)                                    = 4096
10125/1:         0.0071 stat64(0x0808E630, 0x08089B40)                  Err#2 ENOENT
10125/1:             0x0808E630: "/proc/10125/path/0"
10125/1:         0.0071 lwp_sigmask(3, 0x00020000, 0x00000000)          = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
10125/1:         0.0071 stat64(0x0808E792, 0x08047600)                  Err#2 ENOENT
10125/1:             0x0808E792: "/usr/sbin/echo"
10125/1:         0.0072 lwp_sigmask(3, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)          = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
10125/1:         0.0072 lwp_sigmask(3, 0x00020000, 0x00000000)          = 0xFFBFFEFF [0x0000FFFF]
```

Comment: Maybe you obfuscated the cause of the problem? Are the owners equal, is the dir /var/opt/xxxxxxxx a symbolic link?
What is the response when you call checkip.sh with an non-existing file or with a file without read permission?

Comment: the way Id go about troubleshooting this is use the strace system call and grep for system calls that create file descriptors. Read the instructions here:
http://ss64.com/bash/strace.html 
ETA: I see you tried truss.

Comment: Good to know about strace but unfortunately i am having following error.`ERROR: tracer already exists`

Comment: You can paste the output of truss for when it works and when it doesn't (you can use a link to pastebin.com or something, because it's going to be huge probably). Maybe there is something there.

Comment: `ls -l /var/opt/xxxxxxxx/testip` : is this file a symbolic link, rewritten every second, unreadible or very big?

Comment: What does `stat /proc/$$/path/0` show?

Comment: stat does not work here.

Comment: What does `readlink` say about that link? Do other files in that directory cause the same problem? What does `ls -l` say about the input file itself.

Comment: The file has no problem at all. because the same file has been copied in different directories and tested. But only in one particular directory if I keep the file,I see the problem.

Comment: just try a lot. `cp -r xxxxxxxx x2`; `mv testip testip.org; cp testip.org testip`; `cp testip testip2`; `fuser testip`; `mv xxxxxxxx x2; cp -r x2 xxxxxxxx`. Something should give us an answer!

Comment: What is your invoking shell? It is responsible for setting up the fds for the `ksh` process, which then reads and executes your script. I can reproduce both of your scenarios in bash if I invoke the script in two different ways. With a "<" it reliably gives my a good symbolic link. But if I do `cat someFile | ./checkip.sh`, which should be equivalent to stdin redirection, I get an unterminated symlink like you do. Hope this gives you some food for thought.

Comment: [continued from above]

Look at your invoking shell and try to figure out the conditions when it sets up a symlik for fd of 0 and when it may choose to pipe the file straight into stdin of the child process.

Comment: Also, try adding `pfiles $$` in before the `var=...` line and observe the FD of 0 in `pfiles` output for both cases. This may give you additional clues.

Answer (score 0):

This is down to your "if [ -f" statement.  It's specifically checking if the *FILE* (-f) exists.  What you've got there in all examples are links, not files.  The resolution of those links determine whether the -f query is satisfied or not.  When I checked the /var results with an ls on my own system, the link pointed to a character special device, which won't satsify the -f "file exists" criteria.

I'm confused about the direction into the script though.  I don't see anywhere that it's actually using the input that you specify.  The "var" is entirely self-contained within the script as you have it specified above.  To get the -f working on a specified filename, you'd have to do something along the lines of 
  if [ -f $1 ]
(unless your script changes between the posting and the example runs).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same behavior by removing the file at the beginning of the script:

```
# cat ./aaa
#!/bin/ksh

rm -f /tmp/file.tmp

var=`ls -lrt /proc/$$/path/0`
echo $var
if [[  -f /proc/$$/path/0 ]]; then
    echo "found file descriptor"
else
    echo "file descriptor not found"
fi
```

Then:

```
# touch /tmp/file.tmp
# ./aaa < /tmp/file.tmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 25 14:52 /proc/784/path/0
file descriptor not found
```

My suggestion is to execute `ls -li /var/opt/xxxxxxxx/testip` a few times and I'm almost sure you will see different inode with each run, or run it before and after executing the script.

I think that in your case the file is overwritten by something else and you always see the file present but when you launch this script the redirection opens for reading the file from a certain inode, and before the 1st command is executed, the input file is re-written to a different inode which is not know to the script.